# MP0303_SyncAssetEquipment - Commission Date field cannot be blank

Tags: infor-eam

I am getting the following error using infor-eam MP0303_SyncAssetEquipment:

"Commission Date field cannot be blank."

I have coded for the commission date:

```
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE = new MP0303_SyncAssetEquipment_001.DATETIME();
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.YEAR = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.YEAR;
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.MONTH = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.MONTH;
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.DAY = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.DAY;
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.HOUR = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.HOUR;
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.MINUTE = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.MINUTE;
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.SECOND = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.SECOND;
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.SUBSECOND = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.SUBSECOND;
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.TIMEZONE = result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.TIMEZONE;
```

But still getting the same error message.  Any ideas?

Thanks Before Hand

Answer (score 1):

You are missing these:

```
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.qualifier = new MP0303_SyncAssetEquipment_001.DATETIMEqual();
getrequest.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.qualifier = (MP0303_SyncAssetEquipment_001.DATETIMEqual)result.AssetEquipment.COMMISSIONDATE.qualifier;
```